# Section/theorem/definition headers in margin

Tags: marginpar, ntheorem, section-titles

I would like a style in which sectioning headers along with theorem/definitions are in the margin. I particularly like the style used in *An Introduction
to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its Applications* (4th edition).

A sample:

[image: Excerpt of Li and Vitányi (2019)]

I suspect that I could cobble something together with the ntheorem and titlesec packages, but as it didn't appear obvious how to do that, I am hoping that someone already has before I try.